Proving that $imf \cong A^{\sim}$ in the context of universal properties.
Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a certain function. Let us have the following equivalence relation on $A$: If $a,a^{'}\in A$ then $a \sim a^{'}$ iff $f(a) = f(a^{'})$.
This exercise appears in the context of universal properties. The author has shown that $A^{\sim}$ (The set of equivalence classes of $A$) is an initial object of the category whose objects are the functions that map equivalent elements to the same images (here the equivalence relation considered is the one I defined previously). What I'm tasked with doing is proving that $im f$ is also an initial object, from where we can then conclude that $im f \cong A^{\sim}$.
To do this, we have to prove that there is one and only one morphism between the object $(f,im f)$ and the object $(\phi, Z)$ where $Z$ is any set and $\phi: A \rightarrow Z$ has the desired properties.
I already have the proof done. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out if the following part is correct:
Since $f: A \rightarrow imf$ is surjective, then if $y \in imf$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $y = f(a)$. Now I need to define a function $\delta: imf \rightarrow Z$ such that $\phi = \delta \circ f $. I defined $\delta$ by being that function that for each $y \in imf$, gives us $\phi(a)$, where $a \in A$ such that $y = f(a)$.
I'm not quite sure if $\delta$ is well defined. I know that if $ a,a^{'} \in A$ and $f(a)=f(a^{'})=y$ then $\phi(a)=\phi(a^{'})$, since $a \cong a^{'}$, so that should mean that there isn't any problem with $\delta$. But I believe I'm missing something. Could somebody help me, please?
PS: I'm aware that perhaps I shouldn't have called the function from $A$ to $imf$ also $f$.

Your argument is correct. In homotopy type theory, you would interpret the "there exists" statement as $|\Sigma_{a : A} y = f(a)|$; in order to eliminate the propositional truncation and get $\phi(a)$, you have to prove that any two elements of $\Sigma_{a : A} y = f(a)$ give the same answer, which follows as you showed.

Thank you very much!
